# Server side rendering + routing with Riot.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, riot.js

I'm using Node + Riot.js + Grapnel routing library (which can work on both client and server). I managed how to set up routing on the client but I can't figure the way to make it work on the server.

The current functionality of my client router is simple. I'm just sending `opts.route` to the proper component and then it mounts the requested page (which is also a component) to a `div`.

```
<x-layout>
  <div id="app-body"></div>

  <script>
    this.on('mount update', function() {
      riot.mount('#app-body', 'x-page-' + opts.route);
    });
  </script>
</x-layout>
```

But with `riot.render(tag, {page: 'dashboard'})` it doesn't mounts the `<x-page-dashboard>` to `#app-body`.

When I remove `this.on('mount update' ...` wrapper it gives me an error

```
.../node_modules/riot/riot.js:1918
TypeError: (ctx || document).querySelectorAll is not a function`
```

which is obvious, because Node can't perform DOM manipulations.

I also tried to dynamically load components, like this

```
// Riot doesn't compiles such expressions `<x-page-{opts.route}>`
var tag = riot.tag2('x-layout', '<div id="app-body"><x-page-{opts.route}></x-page-{opts.route}></div>');
riot.render(tag, {route: 'dashboard'}); // --> <x-layout><div id="app-body"><x-page-{opts.route}></x-page-{opts.route}></div></x-layout>

// Compiles but not mounts (empty tag)
var tag = riot.tag2('x-layout', '<div id="app-body" riot-tag="x-page-{opts.route}"></div>');
riot.render(tag, {route: 'dashboard'}); // --> <x-layout><div id="app-body" riot-tag="x-page-dashboard"></div></x-layout>

// It's only working when I hard coded the tag name
var tag = riot.tag2('x-layout', '<x-page-dashboard></x-page-dashboard>');
riot.render(tag, {route: 'dashboard'}); // <x-layout><x-page-dashboard>___ CHILDREN COMPONENTS... ____</x-page-dashboard></x-layout>
```

Is there any possible way to implement isomorphic rendering + routing? I'm almost there, just need to pass somehow component name dynamically through opts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it. The solution was to use `name="app_body"` attribute but not `id="app-body"` as I was trying to do.

```
<x-layout>
  <div name="app_body"></div>

  <script>
    this.mountPage = (page) => {
      riot.mount(this.app_body, 'x-page-' + page);
    }

    if (opts.route)
      this.mountPage(opts.route)
  </script>
</x-layout>
```

Thanks to GianlucaGuarini response https://github.com/riot/riot/issues/1450#issuecomment-165984208

Working example https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/riot-app-example